Appium Wdio not run webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51238
When I try to run a trial test, I have an error - ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51238.The port is different all the time
I do not understand what the problem is, the Internet search did not give any 1 option for a solution

We need to know more details to answer this. The said error is fired when a request violates Same-origin-policy. Protocol, port and host must literally match, ex. localhost doesn't match to 127.0.0.1. There might be other reasons for this error to fire too.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
